# I want to fix scrolldown in my vertical dropdown menu when I hover it hides before reaching last elements https://ibb.co/e4OZ3z

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, css, sticky-menu

I want to fix scroll-down in my vertical drop-down menu when I hover it hides before reaching last elements https://ibb.co/e4OZ3z
My website url is: https://www.equipus.com/

Comment: The issue is with sticky menu. Can you remove the sticky menu?

Comment: can you please give me more details from where to disable it, I'm using magento 1.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the sticky menu by 2 ways:

**Method 1:**

Goto

> /js/magiccart/magicmenu.js

and Comment out the below lines:

```
if($(this).scrollTop()>500){
    $('.header-sticker').addClass('header-container-fixed');
}else{
    $('.header-sticker').removeClass('header-container-fixed');
}
```

**Method 2:**
Goto

> skin/frontend/alosupermarket/supermarket06/css/styles.css

and comment out the below code:

```
.header-container-fixed {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10000;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: you are a star @Sukumar Gorai ,Perfect!